# Couchbase-Server Community Edition 5.0.1 Installation issue on MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.2

Tags: macos, installation, couchbase, macos-high-sierra

I had previous working copy of the Couchbase Server community Edition 4*, this stopped opening the Admin Console page from the menu options post upgrade to the macOs high sierra.

Action performed

- I have wiped deleted and re-install with the latest version of CB Server 5.0.1.
- Clicked the Couchbase Server.app to begin with it has pinned the couchbase icon in the menu bar.
- Selected "Open Admin Console"
- Browser complained 'Safari Can't Connect to 127.0.0.1:8091'

Checked if there is any process running? And found there are.

`Rizwans-MacBook-Pro:logs rizwan$ ps -ef | grep couch
  501  6411  6396   0  9:08AM ??         0:01.48 /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/beam.smp -A 16 -- -root /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /Users/rizwan -- -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 21100 inet_dist_listen_max 21299 -sasl sasl_error_logger false -hidden -name babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1 -setcookie nocookie -run ns_babysitter_bootstrap -- -couch_ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.d/capi.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.d/geocouch.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/local.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Preferences/couchbase-server.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/etc/couch-platform.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/etc/couch-custom.ini -ns_babysitter cookiefile "/Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/couchbase-server.cookie" -ns_server config_path "/Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config" -ns_server pidfile "/Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/couchbase-server.pid" -ns_server cookiefile "/Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/couchbase-server.cookie-ns-server" -ns_server dont_suppress_stderr_logger true -ns_server loglevel_stderr info
  501  6704  6411   0  9:12AM ??         0:00.80 /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/beam.smp -A 16 -sbt u -P 327680 -K true -swt low -MMmcs 30 -e102400 -- -root /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /Users/rizwan -- -smp enable -setcookie nocookie -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 21100 inet_dist_listen_max 21299 error_logger false -sasl sasl_error_logger false -user user_io -run child_erlang child_start ns_bootstrap -- -couch_ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.d/capi.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/default.d/geocouch.ini /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/etc/couchdb/local.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Preferences/couchbase-server.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/etc/couch-platform.ini /Users/rizwan/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/etc/couch-custom.ini`

- Further to it try the couchbase server starting from the command line via the script available in download. It failed with the below log

> Rizwans-MacBook-Pro:Resources rizwan$ ./start-server.sh
>
> Starting epmd ...
>
> Starting Couchbase Server ...
>
> {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},"Protocol: ~tp: the name babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1 seems to be in use by another Erlang node",["inet_tcp"]}
>
> {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.57>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,true}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},{reductions,1105}],[]]}
>   {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[['babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1',longnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
>   {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
>   {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}],[]]}
>   {error_logger,{{2018,1,7},{20,33,26}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
>   {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
>
> Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
>   Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: The issue was resolved by installing another version of cb server for enterprise edition, to work upon further I had used the docker containers images for cbserver with the same community edition